# Could not load Custom form field Type in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.1

I want to represent one to many relationship to persist purchase order with purchase order deatils.So I tried to add purchase order detail list by increment a table row for each detail.For that, 
I developed PurchaseOrderDetailType form type as follows

```
class PurchaseOrderDetailType extends AbstractType{


   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
     $builder->add('item',EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:InvtItem',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('item')
                ->orderBy('item.description', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'description',
     ))
        ->add('unit_price')
        ->add('qty')
        ->add('price');

   }

   /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderDetails'
    ));
  }
 }
```

Then I uses it in PurchaseOrderType class like this

```
 class PurchaseOrderType extends AbstractType
    {
         /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('supplier',EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
            'label'=>'Supplier',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('supplier')
                    ->orderBy('supplier.name', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ))
        ->add('purchaseOrderDetails',CollectionType::class,array(
            'entry_type' => PurchaseOrderDetailType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true
        ))
        ->add('status');
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder'
    ));
}
 }
```

Then I got this error => Could not load type "PurchaseOrderDetailType"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Comment: So if you are using Symfony 3 or Symfony 2.8 and the EntityType::class syntax, you must put - `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;`

Comment: yeah I have imported all the libraries correctly.I didn't mention them here.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because of this -

> **EntityType Field** - A special ChoiceType field that's designed to load options from a Doctrine entity.

The entity type has just one required option: the entity which should be listed inside the choice field:

**An example**

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    // query choices from this entity
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',

    // use the User.username property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'username',

    // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
    // 'multiple' => true,
    // 'expanded' => true,
));
```

So you have to use following in the beginning.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
```

**And**

Try replacing `EntityType::class` by `entity` .

**Update :**

I think, In Symfony 3 you need to use [FQCN](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form) (fully-qualified class name) instead of an instance of the form (or a string reference to a service).

Comment: I did your suggestions but same error is still occurring.

Comment: Do I want to register custom form types?

Comment: You can see that I used FQCN all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I just missed the namespace for the class PurchaseOrderDetailType